# How can I set my window to cover exactly the virtual screen area?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, size, dpi

I can get the virtual screen size from System.Windows.SystemParameters, but since WPF doesn't work in pixels but in DPI-units I can't directly use this.
How do I make my WPF window (Border=none) cover exactly the entire virtual screen ?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have so far (e.g. the code that is geting the size of the virtual screen, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked fine:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;

    this.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
    this.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;

    this.Left = 0;
    this.Top = 0;
}
```

Is this what you were thinking (but didn't post)?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;

    this.Left = 0;
    this.Top = 0;

    Point screenPoint = new Point(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);

    Point translatedPoint = this.PointFromScreen(screenPoint);

    this.Height = translatedPoint.Y;
    this.Width = translatedPoint.X;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the Virtual Desktop is not necessarily rectangular.